# How To Remove lines with non-ALPHANUMERIC characters with exceptions from an email list

Tags: sed, grep

I used the following code on a text file with  /n as the delimiter that has about 40 million lines.

> 'egrep -e -i [[:alnum:]._@] file > temp && mv temp file'

I need to use BRE.

Apparently, after doing this, I was still able to find several lines that contained / ; -, which are supposed to not be acceptable characters. . _ @ are the only acceptable non-alphanumeric characters.

I usually use something like:

> 'sed -e '/string/d' file > temp && mv temp file

What would the proper command be to carry this out using BRE?

Comment: Do you actually have a question? Because "I used the following code...." and "I need to use BRE." are not questions...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What is a command that will remove any line that has a non-alphanumeric character except for _ . and @? What I usually use is not working, so I need something else and don't know what.

Comment: I would suggest `tr -dc "A-Za-z0-9_.@ \n" < input > output`... Or `tr -dc "[:alnum:][:space:]_.@" < input > output` if your version of `tr` supports character classes, which most more recent versions do...

Comment: Thank you very much. tr worked for changing delimiters so it should work.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/[^[:alnum:]_@]/d' file
```

Edit inline deleting any line that contains a character that is not alphanumeric or an underscore or an at sign.

Answer (score 1):

using sed:

```
sed -n -e '/@/p' -e '/^[[:alnum:]]*$/p' your_file
```

technically speaking, email detection using re is not very nice. but anyways, you have your software.

http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: Thank you! I read that article, which was very helpful. I have a SMTP validation script and it works really well for txt and csv files. But, in trying to lighten its load, I am trying to pre-scrub the list to a degree. Like that article said, my rules may be too strict anyway. But, getting rid of characters such as !#$%^&*(){}[]|\/":',<> is really what I am after here for this file. For csv files, I would obviously keep the " , because they are delimiters. So, in this case, would egrep -v '[\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\{\}\[\]\|\\\/\"\:\'\,\<\>\'\-{2}*]' file > temp be the proper way to get rid of these

Comment: @envisisoft are you asking a question? oh man, if you are writing re ugly like this, for your own sake, change a smarter way to do it just in case you need to come back.

Comment: No, normally I am using sed -e '/\;/d' file > temp && mv temp file but wanted a one-liner. I am confused on how to write this out in a single command instead of a list of them.